# How can I set up Sublime Text 3 so that I can search only for folders and files inside my project?

Tags: directory, sublimetext3, text-editor

My question is very concise. I am looking for a way to filter only my search to find my files and especially my folders.

I tried some goto search methods like goto anything (ctrl + P), but it does not match my folders. What is the best solution for that? is that a plugin recommendation or something?

Comment: Have you added any folders to the window? The default for `Find in Files` is `Open files and folders` (in the `Where` field), so generally if you have added folders it should already be searching in your project. Also `Goto Anything` only considers files that are visible in the side bar, which is controlled by the folders you add.

Comment: @OdatNurd Yes. I added through the three horizontal dotted botton on the right side of Open files and folders field. I chose the option of "add folder" and then I select the main folder that holds all my projects' directories. I am missing something.

Comment: You want to use `Project > Add Folder to Project` and select a folder from there; then the side bar will show you the files in that folder, `Find in Files` will search them, and `Goto Anything` will be able to open them too. Sublime is going to scan for every file and folder under the folder(s) you add, so be wary of opening a folder with a lot of files in it (like the root of your hard drive or your home directory).

Comment: I know what you talk about when you refer to "a lot of files in it". node_modules is one of this file, but this is an exception. All the rest, I try to keep all the folders and files as organized and clean as possible. I already added the folder to Project, and all of them are displaying in the side bar.

Comment: I have tried a new plugin called **project manager** to handle with these folders better in separated windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl + Shift + F and in the Where: box, type: `<project>`.

Comment: That's a feasible solution. But when I search the results, it displays only directories with this message: "ERROR: Unable to open file" showing in which one of them. I wonder if there is a way to find and track the current searched location of the folder inside the project.